# How can I daemonize node?

Tags: node.js

Is there a universally accepted means of deamonizing (and of course, later communicating through signals or some abstraction thereon) a node script?

That is, is there a Node equivalent of:

```
if (fork())
    // parent process, die
    exit(1);
// we're a daemon
```

Comment: see [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Node Web Development]

> The following is a list of ways to run Node as a background daemon on
>   different platforms:
>
> - [nodejs-autorestart](https://github.com/shimondoodkin/nodejsautorestart) manages a Node instance on Linux which uses Upstart (Ubuntu, Debian, and so on).
> - [fugue](https://github.com/pgte/fugue) watches a Node server, restarting it if it crashes.
> - [forever](https://github.com/indexzero/forever) is a small commandline Node script which ensures a script will run "forever".
> - [node-init](https://github.com/frodwith/node-init) is a Node script which turns your Node application into a LSB-compliant init script. LSB being a specification of Linux
>     compatibility.

Comment: I thought this book was terrible. It's not thorough and advertises a ton of third-party code instead of using built-in Node modules (as you would expect from the title). It should be called "Web Development with Node.js Tools" or something.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a built-in way to do this in Node. Take a look at [Writing Daemon's in JavaScript with Node.js](http://slashed.posterous.com/writing-daemons-in-javascript-with-nodejs-0) for one implementation (warning: this is relatively old and Node moves fast--I haven't tested it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Upstart works well for me, though I'm having an issue when I serve over https. Here's the tutorial I used:

http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/run_nodejs_as_a_service_on_ubuntu_karmic/

You can use node's process object to send/handle signals.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out there really isn't a way to do this in Node directly.  You really need to run it using [foreverjs](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever).  The reason you need to run it using a monitor like forever, is because error thrown by your code will often result in the entire Node process to quit and exit.  A monitor will look for this occurring and restart the process immediately.

It is also important to note that while the process is restarting, your server will not respond to request so plan ahead if you expect this to be a problem and make sure that you have a few servers processes running under a load-balancer.